# LINQ - Update null integer data field

Tags: linq, null, linq-to-entities, field

I have got a field with data type `int?` price and allow null, when I set

```
book.price = null;
```

and update, it is not saved and does not throw any exceptions, when I change value # null, it is ok. I want set it null.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the field is nullable in the database and is reflected so in the dbml.
Regenerate the dbml for the table just to be sure. (Drop tabel from dbml and add again)

All I can say is it works for us so this is very strange.

Answer (score 0):

I am not suer I understand the question, this part is unclear:

> "when I change value # null, it is ok"

Did you make sure to call

```
db.SaveChanges();
```

(where [db] is the name of your Entites object)
It is a simple mistake that I make often :P

Comment: it does not seem that the problem was that. because when the value was changed, i guess what value # null is such as 100, than it works as expected. problem must be something else.